# jQuery inserting to multiple divs

Tags: jquery

**Problem:** jQuery inserts the `<li>`-element to both divs, but it should only insert it to the first list.

**HTML structure**

```
<div id="participantsList1">
    <div class="inputList"></div>
</div>

<div id="participantsList2">
    <div class="inputList"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
this._itemList = $("#participantsList1");
 $('<li class="badge">' + WCF.String.escapeHTML(data.label) + ' <span class="icon icon-remove pointer"></span></li>').insertBefore(".inputList", this._itemList);
```

Edit: `participantsList1` is not a static value..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to access element by index in collection. The eq is zero based index to to access first element you need to pass zero :eq.

```
this._itemList = $("#participantsList1:eq(0)");
```

Comment: or as an alternative...  `.first()`

Comment: this._itemList is changeable.

Comment: what isn't changeable?  `.inputList`?  How about `$('.inputList:eq(0)')` - there are a lot of options...

Comment: Additionally, if you want every element **except** the first, `$('.classname:gt(0)')` would select all elements except the first.

Answer (score 0):

You can just be more specific:

```
[...].insertBefore("#participantsList1 .inputList", this._itemList);
```

Comment: this._itemList is changeable. I am not able to do it like this.

Comment: You can always grab that bit out:
foo = $("#participantsList1 .inputList");
bar = $("#participantsList1 .inputList:nth-child(1)"); // or whatever you want

.insertBefore(foo, bar);

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `$('<li class="badge">'` refers to **any** `li` element with `class = badge`.

You can use `parent > child` selector: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

`.insertBefore("#participantsList1 > inputList").`

Full example:

```
$('<li class="badge">' + WCF.String.escapeHTML(data.label) + ' <span class="icon icon-remove pointer"></span></li>').insertBefore("#participantsList1 > .inputList", this._itemList);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem myself:

```
$('<li class="badge">' + WCF.String.escapeHTML(data.label) + ' <span class="icon icon-remove pointer"></span></li>').insertBefore($(".inputList", this._itemList));
```

I had to pass an jQuery object to `insertBefore()` (missing `$(...)`)